# How to make a legacy Identity provider compatible with a federated login standard?

Tags: openid-connect, legacy, federated-identity

Let's call A a platform that provides APIs and web applications. A includes an Authentication/Authorization Server that uses OAuth2 and has its own users (Auth0 is the choosen solution)
Everything works well for users belonging to A organization.

A organization has business partners, those partners have their platform, that uses some kind of legacy authentication. Let's call B this platform.

- B wants to access A services
- A trust B
- B authenticated users should access A services without logging a second time on A

A allows federated logins and it seems that B could be considered as an Identity Provider following some standard understood by A (OIDC for instance but other are known by A: [Auth0 SSO](https://auth0.com/docs/sso/outbound-single-sign-on)).

I would like to know how to transform B to implement a standard federated login solution without changing completely the way users are authenticated on B.

I imagine some kind of interfaces, with an adapter that would implements a standard like OIDC

The solutions I found always imply migrating from the legacy solution to a standard solution.

Answer (score 1):

Good question - since OIDC does not specify how authentication should take place - only the messages before and after.

The interface concept exists for some providers, such as in the [Curity SDK](https://github.com/curityio/anonymous-authenticator/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/io/curity/identityserver/plugin/anonymous/authentication/AnonymousAuthenticatorRequestHandler.kt), which has an extensible authenticator concept - you will find lots of them in the [GitHub Repos](https://github.com/curityio?q=authenticator).

**IDEALLY**

The approach would be roughly as follows:

- A custom authenticator is written
- The custom authenticator is plugged into your Authorization Server
- The legacy system needs to be updated to present a login screen for a new type of request message
- The legacy system needs to be updated to provide an authentication result differently

**IN PRACTICE**

Most providers don't support this type of solution, and the impact on the legacy system may not be trivial. Also it would be easy to get the security a little wrong.

Therefore it is common to instead specify that partners must meet standards based prerequisites (such as SAML or OIDC) before they can integrate with you. That is generally the safer approach.

Comment: Well, is it possible for my partner to meet standards, but only partially, in order for my system to recognize them as standard identity provider, but without having to rework the way they use authentication on their apps/services ?

Comment: Potentially it is possible - they would need to do some additive work and then both forms of login would work. But as I said, in practice this is unlikely to be supported by your Authorization Server. There is no standard design pattern for this and you are very unlikely to find a quick solution. If it was me, my next step would be to explain the industry standard approach to stakeholders - where business partners must meet the prerequisite of using a standards based identity provider.